# Send Logs to multiple syslog servers

Tags: rhel, syslog

Previously we were using one Logging server. But now we have added one extra Logging server which will also be storing logs received from client . I need to know how to add these two Syslog servers on client's syslog.conf file. So that both syslog servers receive the logs at same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have not specified, and also for the benefit of other readers, I will describe what to do using syslog-ng and rsyslog to have a server logging simultaneously to two remote syslog servers.

If you have syslog-ng logging to a central syslog server, modify /etc/syslog-ng.conf

As an example:

```
source s_src { unix-dgram("/dev/log"); internal();
         file("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel"));
};

destination d_loghost {udp("10.10.1.1" port(514));};
log { source(s_src); destination(d_loghost); };
```

To syslog to a 2nd destination, add:

```
destination d_loghost2 {udp("10.10.1.2" port(514));};
log { source(s_src); destination(d_loghost2); };
```

If running `rsyslog`, then actually it is simpler.The configuration file is /etc/rsyslog.conf

Where you find a destination:

```
*.* @10.10.1.1:514
```

you add a 2nd destination:

```
*.* @10.10.1.2:514
```

After changing the configuration, the syslog daemons in the client side need to be restart. Being it respectively,

```
sudo service syslog-ng restart
```

or

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

As the syslog daemon sends all messages to all destinations configured, unless you explicitly filter out services or log levels, you do not need to configure anything else [in the client side]. Both will receive exactly the same logs.

Comment: FYI for other folks who may stumble across this.  `syslogd` is virtually the same as rsyslog.  The same procedure can be done for `/etc/syslog.conf`

Comment: Can you tell why it sends one packet per minute when specify 127.0.0.1 udp 514 as destination?

Comment: @watou Please read our FAQ and open new questions with your issues/queries.

Comment: [How do I setup rsyslog to send all logs to multiple remote servers?](https://serverfault.com/q/522341) and its answer imply that you cannot have just multiple actions as described for `rsyslog`. Can someone clarify?

Comment: @pt1 would advise opening a new question