# (When) are different queue file names needed when logging to multiple servers?

Tags: rsyslog

I would like to setup rsyslog to log to multiple servers. For the moment it should be based on UDP, but later on it might change to TCP or RELP.

I found multiple ressources that explain how to do so, among them:

- [Send Logs to multiple syslog servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244707/send-logs-to-multiple-syslog-servers)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/522341/how-do-i-setup-rsyslog-to-send-all-logs-to-multiple-remote-servers

The first one recommends a short:

```
*.* @10.10.1.1:514
*.* @10.10.1.2:514
```

While the second one quotes https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/reliable_forwarding.html:

> Be careful that you use different queue file names for the second action, else you will mess up your system.

and proposes a longer configuration:

```
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

$ActionQueueType LinkedList
$ActionQueueFileName Forward1
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on
*.* @@server1

$ActionQueueType LinkedList
$ActionQueueFileName Forward2
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on
*.* @@server2
```

The two recommendations seem contradictory to me. (When) are different queue file names (and the associated configuration settings like `$ActionQueueType`) needed? And in what way would my system be messed up if I don't follow recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

In your examples you've used two different protocols, so just to clarify:

To forward logs via UDP, use one "@" sign and to forward logs via TCP use two "@@" signs at the beginning.

```
*.* @localhost:10514;json-template                 # forward via UDP
```

To make it more clear, however, the RainerScript syntax can be used, which would look like the following:

```
# load omfwd module
module(load="omfwd")

*.* action(type="omfwd" target="127.0.0.1" port="10514" protocol="udp")
```

---

**When are different queue file names needed when logging to multiple servers?**

Queues are useful in scenarios where there is a risk of losing log data due to high log volumes or unreliable network connections, as they allow logs messages to be temporarily stored in memory or on disk until it can be forwarded to a log server.

> Each input to rsyslog is through one or more threads, which gather the
> log messages and add them to the main queue. Worker threads then pull
> messages off the main queue and deliver them to their destinations
> and/or add the message to an action queue. If a worker is unable to
> deliver messages to a destination, all progress of that queue will
> block until that delivery is able to succeed (or it hits the retry
> limit and permanently fails). If you don’t want this to block all log
> processing, you should make an action queue for that destination (or
> group of destinations). [1]

**Are different queue file names needed when logging to multiple servers?**

In general I'd say **no**, as it isn't necessary in most cases and rsyslog is capable of handling multiple destinations in a single queue without issue.

If, however, you're noticing performance issues or you're losing logs, they can be a great tool to solve these problems.

---

If you want to know more about queues, you might want to look into:

- [Turning Lanes and Rsyslog Queues](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/whitepapers/queues_analogy.html)
- [Understand Rsyslog Queues](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/concepts/queues.html)
- [Solving Rsyslog Performance Issues](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/login/articles/06_lang.pdf), [1]